# Custom layout for ALL errors in CakePHP 2.1

Tags: php, cakephp

How do I use a custom layout for my errors in CakePHP 2.1?

I have looked through the docs and seen various mentions of custom handlers etc but nothing on choosing the layout to use... Any ideas?

In versions of CakePHP before like 1.3 you could create an AppError class but this would no longer work as CakeError is now depreciated and doing anything like that is scorned at according to the docs for new applications.

Answer (score 3):

You can change layout in beforeRender() function as below :-

```
public function beforeRender(){
  if($this->name == 'CakeError'){
      $this->layout = 'error';
   }        
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is what I did in CakePHP 2.2.2: I changed the exception renderer in core.php and extended ExceptionRenderer with MyExceptionRenderer overriding just one of the parent's methods. The distribution already includes the file app/View/Layouts/error.ctp so I just edited it a bit.

I also noticed CakeError is deprecated so this worked for me.

app/Config/core.php:

```
Configure::write('Exception', array(
  'handler' => 'ErrorHandler::handleException',
  'renderer' => 'MyExceptionRenderer',
  'log' => true
));
```

app/Lib/Error/MyExceptionRenderer.php:

```
App::uses('ExceptionRenderer', 'Error');

class MyExceptionRenderer extends ExceptionRenderer {

  protected function _outputMessage($template) {
    $this->controller->layout = 'error';
    parent::_outputMessage($template);
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

in the core.php I switch my error handler and exception handler to a custom one:

```
App::uses('MyErrorHandler', 'Tools.Error');
Configure::write('Error', array(
    'handler' => 'MyErrorHandler::handleError',
    'level' => E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED & ~E_STRICT,
    'trace' => true
));

Configure::write('Exception', array(
    'handler' => 'MyErrorHandler::handleException',
    'renderer' => 'Tools.MyExceptionRenderer',
    'log' => true
));
```

then you should put your classes in `Lib/Error/` (either plugin or not)

example: https://github.com/dereuromark/tools/tree/2.0/Lib/Error

Comment: All I want to do is change the layout O_o do I really need to write all that code???

Comment: Oh, I assumed you wanted to do more.. Well, for a layout only there might be easier solutions - e.g. in AppController beforeRender (check on Controller == Error).

Comment: I think i used this in 1.3: `if ($this->name == 'Error') { // switch layout with $this->layout = 'some' }`

Answer (score 0):

Just write

```
$this->layout = 'my_error'
```

in your error400.ctp and error500.ctp files

in your View/Errors/404.ctp View/Errors/500.ctp

like this

```
<?php $this->layout = 'my_error' ?>
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

@faferuziel / @fetruzie
best regards